# Add new file upload field

Tags: javascript, html

Maybe I'm just being stupid here, but when I'm clicking "Add New" it's just loading upload.php

It's not adding another input

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.add_more').click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          $(this).before("<input name='file[]' type='file'/>");
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="post">
      <input name="file[]" type="file" />
      <button class="add_more">Add More Files</button>
      <input type="submit" value="Upload File" id="upload"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Appreciate anyone who can tell me where I've slipped up.

Comment: your code is fine. where is jquery library?

Comment: I mean there is no error in this code. I know some browser treat the default button as submit. but he is using prevent default for that. so everything in his code is fine except jquery library.

Comment: Yeah. You're right. I thought the parent file had it included but I was wrong. This was a school boy error!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code work fine you should just add jQuery lib as you could see below, `e.preventDefault()` will prevent button from submitting the form :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps.

---

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.add_more').click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          $(this).before("<input name='file[]' type='file'/>");
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="post">
      <input name="file[]" type="file" />
      <button type='button' class="add_more">Add More Files</button>
      <input type="submit" value="Upload File" id="upload"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am stupid here why e.preventDefault() didn't work?

Comment: You're not stupid @BhojendraNepal - it was me. School boy error, I thought the parent file had the library included. My bad!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.add_more').click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          $(this).before("<input name='file[]' type='file'/>");
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="post">
      <input name="file[]" type="file" />
      <button type='button' class="add_more">Add More Files</button>
      <input type="submit" value="Upload File" id="upload"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please explain your solution. Code is not enough.

Comment: both are same solution